# CosmosDB MongoDB API doesn't seem to use automatically created index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, azure-cosmosdb

From the CosmosDB documentation, it states that CosmosDB, when left to default settings, will automatically index all fields for every inserted document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing

When executing the following query using the MongoDB .NET client though, the RU increases from 3 RU to 7000 RU when my collection gets (a lot) bigger:

```
var existing = _mongoClient
            .GetDatabase("testDb")
            .GetCollection<AssaySample>("documents")
            .AsQueryable()
            .Any(d => d.ExternalReference == externalReference);
```

This means no index is being used when trying to resolve this query. Looking at the indices that were built by CosmosDB itself, there is no mention of any of the fields in our documents:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xDdP.png)

When trying to add the index for this field though, there is an error saying there already is an index on this column:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPN7e.png)

So what is going on here? Is CosmosDB effectively creating indices and is that why I can't add an index myself. And if it is, why is my query behaving as if it's not using an index?

Comment: Are you using a partitioned collection?

Comment: Hi Jesse - yes this is a partitioned collection. I am wondering, with or without partitioned collections, I would not expect this increase in RU's?